# Finding loops in graph having an adjacency list (data structure)

Tags: algorithm, graph, adjacency-list

I'm trying to see if a directed graph (or multiple graphs actually) have a loop.
I have an adjacency list like the following:

```
1: [4]
4: [5]
5: [6]
9: [10]
10: [11]
11: [12]
12: [13]
13: [10]
```

I was able to create the algorithm to find if the graph has a cycle and it is working but I'm stuck now since it doesn't work on that list because there are 2 disconnected graphs on that adjacency list.

So my question is how can I find how many graphs are in the adjacency list to process them separately or if there is a better way to handle this, my only intention is to find out if there is a cycle in any of the possible graphs in the list, just a true/false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Algorithm**

Let's perform a series of depth-first searches in the graph. Those. from each vertex that we have never visited, we will launch a depth-first search, which will paint it gray when entering the vertex, and black when exiting. And if the depth-first search tries to go to the gray vertex, it means that we have found a cycle (if the graph is undirected, then the cases when the depth-first search from some vertex tries to go to the ancestor are not counted).
The cycle itself can be restored by walking through the array of ancestors.

[Here](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/finding_cycle) you will find a fairly clear and good solution.

Comment: Thank you, your idea pointed me in the right direction!